# Tracing Tomcat using eclipse diver

Tags: eclipse-plugin, trace

Is it possible to trace application deployed in Tomcat using eclipse diver?

Eclipse Diver: http://eclipsediver.wordpress.com/

I have checked the documentation and have not found details regarding this use case.
Anybody who has managed to do this yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this can help you: http://deviltechie.wordpress.com/2011/05/16/debug-using-apache-tomcat-and-eclipse/
It's allows you to connect Tomcat with Eclipse and trace, step by step, your program.

Comment: This is just debugging. I'm also looking for trace application using diver plugin.